# Convert Avro GenericRecord to SpecificData object while converting Long to Instant

Tags: java, apache-kafka, type-conversion, avro

Hi I am trying to convert generic record I get from kafka to specific object I want to use down the line.

Here is my code

```
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> consumerRecord) {
        TxnEngineEvent event = (TxnEngineEvent) SpecificData.get().deepCopy(TxnEngineEvent.SCHEMA$, consumerRecord.value());
```

The problem conversion from Long to Instant is not working. I get this exception

```
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerStoppingErrorHandler.handle(ContainerStoppingErrorHandler.java:65) ~[spring-kafka-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar:2.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1776) [spring-kafka-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar:2.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1693) [spring-kafka-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar:2.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1619) [spring-kafka-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar:2.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1522) [spring-kafka-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar:2.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1263) [spring-kafka-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar:2.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1009) [spring-kafka-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar:2.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:929) [spring-kafka-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar:2.4.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void de.billpay.klarnabankingservice.consumer.kafka.KafkaSepaIncomingConsumer.listen(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord>)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.time.Instant; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.time.Instant
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1788) [spring-kafka-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar:2.4.5.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.time.Instant
    at com.klarna.messaging.Metadata.put(Metadata.java:204) ~[classes/:na]
```

The field causing this has this schema

```
{"name":"occurred_at","type":{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}
```

I have been able to debug the issue down to point where avro native code is trying to convert the value and the problem is it is assigning the convertor based on class of the field. Since the class is java.lang.Long and the convertor's class is java.time.Instant it doesn't get matched. Is there something I am missing? I wanted to workaround this by implementing my own converter but That would need to be of type java.lang.Long which makes no sense + I can't convert the value to java.time.Instant (No interface method to return even generic Object)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Pietro just add this to consumer factory properties `properties.put("specific.avro.reader", true);` And have listener consume the specific object instead of generic.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way with jackson object mapper

```
ConsumerRecord<Key, Value> singleRecord = records.poll(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
  .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
  .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
  .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

Value value = objectMapper.readValue(String.valueOf(singleRecord.value()), Value.class);
```